# Does the pets provide bonus for the party during quests?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I found a lot of information saying that it provides bonus for the owner of it, but... it somehow doesn't make sense, on a party it's sort of expected it would get a bonus for everybody, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just gives the bonus for the one dweller which has the pet equipped.
Whith your logic it would also mean that a complete room of your vault will get the bonus - what isn't the fact.

Comment: That's so sad =( because pet's that provides extra coins or extra items can go totally useless on this since it could affect only single wasteland explore

Comment: Well not really. If one of your dwellers in a party has a pet with item or cap bonus, you could get more stuff in you current event. I thought you mean things like damage or healing effects. These only count for a single dweller. Though I can't confirm that your party will get more caps and items becouse they are predetermined by the quest you choose. Maybe some else can confirm this. But the Cap bonus is really nice. Since you have really good dwellers they are able to collect more than 10,000 caps and some percent more make a great change.

Comment: Yes but it's hard to know what kind of bonus can affect the party or a single Dweller. Like the bonus caps, or the extra chance of junk and so on.

Maybe a specification on this could be nice from them.